# Kendo window bind - unnecessary repetitive actions

Tags: kendo-ui

I have the kendo grid and in each row I have the first column with link type - for open details in kendo window.

```
<ak-col k-title="Record number">
      <ak-template>                    
          <a click.delegate="openDetails(id)">${id}</a>
      </ak-template>
</ak-col>
```

I need to implement the functionality which provide during kendo window closing confirmation with question for user.
I have done the following:

```
$(this.boardingDetails.element).data("kendoWindow")
    .bind("close", function (e) {
        if (!confirm("All unsaved data will be lost. Are you want to close the window?")) {
           e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

It works fine for first action. But next time I see confirmation question two time, then - three time... etc.

At first I thought that problem in e.preventDefault() action.
But then I remade (just for check) script:

```
var counter = 0;
$(this.boardingDetails.element).data("kendoWindow")
    .bind("close", function (e) {
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
    });
```

And result is the following:
[image]

It means that problem in bind action.

How can I fixed it?

If I use unbind

```
var page = this;
$(this.boardingDetails.element).data("kendoWindow")
    .bind("close", function (e) {
        if (!confirm("All unsaved data will be lost. Are you want to close the window?")) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        $(page.boardingDetails.element).data("kendoWindow").unbind("close");

    });
```

it works wrong. First time I see the question for closing, but if I have answered "no", and then I am trying to close one more time, the window will been closed without the conformation question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show your code where you are creating and showing the window(better yet, create a dojo/fiddle showing the problem).  You are likely creating the window ONCE but binding every time you show it, which causes multiple events.  In your unbind case, don't unbind when you answer NO, only unbind when you close the window.  But the unbind should not be necessary if you CREATE once, BIND once, SHOW multiple times.

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you so much!!! 
Unbind only for confirm == true works fine!